# Xgboost - how to make a custom loss function which depends the value of another column, as well the error

Tags: r, xgboost

I am having issue implementing recency-weighting for xgboost training in R (i.e. passing a weight vector to xgb.dmatrix) - although the weighting affects the learning curve readout for the training set, it does not appear to have any impact at all on the actual model produced - performance in the test set is identical.

I can't seem to get to the bottom of this issue or generate a reproducible example. So instead I would like to pass the Date column of the features to a custom loss function, something like:

```
custom_loss <- function(preds,dat) {
  labels <- getinfo(dat,"label")
  dates <- [a vector corresponding to the dates associated with each prediction]
  grad = f(dates)*-2*(labels - preds)
  hess = f(dates)*2
  [where f is an increasing function of the value in dates, so later samples matter more when training]
  return(list(grad=grad,hess=hess))
}
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this, any suggestions?